# Click on dropdown list doesn't perform

Tags: python, selenium, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEIPC.png)I'm new to python with selenium and for practice. I'm trying to click on this element that is a dropdown list but the element is highlighted but it doesn't click. You find below the code that I've tried and a screenshot and the HTML that I'm inspecting.

```
   driver.implicitly_wait(30)[enter image description here][1]
   time.sleep(10)
   print("The Non fiction is selected")
   # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.ID, "div-nonfiction").click()
   # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.ID, "div-nonfiction").click()
   # button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Nonfiction")
   # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , "//a[contains(text(),'Nonfiction')]").click()
   element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Nonfiction')]")
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
   # action = TouchActions(driver)
   # action.tap(mySelect).perform()
   # mySelect.select_by_visible_text('ATLANTIC')
   # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.ID, "icon-nonfiction").click()
   # # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.ID, "icon-nonfiction").click()
   # # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , "//a[contains(text(),'Nonfiction')]")
   # actions = ActionChains(driver)
   # actions.double_click(choose_category_in_list).perform()

   # driver.find_element_by_link_text("Nonfiction").click()
   # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , "//a[contains(text(),'Nonfiction')]").click()
   # choose_category_in_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH , "//a[contains(text(),'Nonfiction')]").click()  
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Nonfiction")))
   element.click()
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page or at least the HTML of all that page? Not a picture, a code

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code it is hard to make a solid answer, but there are several thing i would try.
First - try using

```
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "your_text")
```

You may need to hover the element first:

```
# finds an element and clicks on it
def find_element_hover_click_element(self, *locator):
    element = self.driver.find_element(*locator)
    hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.click().perform()

# hovers over element (need to provide an element, not a locator here)
def hover_click_element(self, element):
    hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.click().perform()
```

You may also try using xpath, but instead of aiming to the

```
[//a[contains(text(),'Nonfiction')]
```

You may want to find an upper element of the DOM

```
(//div[@id='some_id']//a)
```

But it would be easier if you posted your HTML code here